# Error sending POST from React front end to Django,error status 401

Tags: django, reactjs, axios

I am using Token authentication for Django & React integration.

The below POST method fails in React with status 401,however same method give status 200 ok from POSTMAN(with same token,url and id)

```
axios
      .post(`songs/${id}/like`, {
        headers: { Authorization: `Token ${token}` }})
      .then()
      .catch();
  };
```

I have ensured that I passed all parameters to axios but something got wrong.
Other interaction with backends like login,signup,GET methods work fine.

What are the possible causes for the error ?

I have set CORSORIGINALLOWALL=True.

[image]

Comment: Will you pleease also post what are you passing in header from postman?

Comment: I passes only token in header.

Comment: Will you pelase share the screenshot of that?

Comment: Unfortunately postman keeps crashing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think second param should be data for `axios.post` try the below snippet:

```
axios.post(`songs/${id}/like`, {} , { headers: { Authorization: `Token ${token}` }})
```

Comment: Appreciate your effort,I forgot to add data field